# Installing Linux Mint with Windows dual boot but Windows keeps messing it up

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot

I have been using Windows for a while now but I wanted to revert to Linux, Linux Mint being my choice.

When installing, I wasn't able to create new partition for the Linux installation. Turns out, I have one HDD in my laptop, partitioned into three drives, C, D and E, adding up to a total of four with the system reserved and my laptop won't allow more than four partitions.

I went and cleared the E partition and had 133 GB of unallocated storage. This is what happened.

[image: Screenshot of partitions]

Windows created a random 1 MB drive along with the 500 MB of system reserved. The empty space of E, now merged into D (`sda4`).

I have tried tens of combinations, clearing the unallocated space in as many ways as I can but nothing is working.

Comment: From either Windows or Linux live boot, use a partition management app to resize and convert your D/sda4 into logical partition, then create another logical partition from the free space for Mint

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it's weird that windows can just somehow **merge** unallocated space after deleting a local disk/partition. Anyway, download [GParted](https://gparted.org/) , write it to a usb stick and boot from it. Try to resize your /dev/sda4 drive. After that, you can either create a new partition for mint and let the mint installer handle the rest, or just leave the unallocated space for the installer to detect.